# Iframe from website based on Laravel is blurry on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, laravel, iframe, rendering

I have an issue with showing iframe content from any Laravel website. On mobile devices it's blurry (attached the screenshot). On the same server with the same html content iframe from Laravel's website is blurry but ok not from Laravel.

[difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/089UD.png)

How this is even possible?

I tried to test it on newly installed Laravel and the same problem.

To reproduce:

1. Install Laravel.
2. Create some page with any content.
3. Create HTML document where you have iframe with src to previously created page in Laravel.
4. Open the HTML document in Chrome / web developer tools / device (iPhone 14 or any other).
5. You'll see blurry iframe.

Comment: please provide the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and error in text form if any.

Comment: @Rainysidewalks added steps to reproduce.